# Disabling reneg-sec on openvpn

Tags: openvpn, cryptography

I'm using a `kylemanna/openvpn` image (Openvpn 2.4) with default settings and I've noticed that each client disconnects for 1 minute every 1 hour. I believe it's connected to `reneg-sec`, which defaults to 3600 seconds.

This is an issue for me, because I'm using this openvpn to provide an API to some proprietary devices, and 1 minute of downtime per device + 1 minute of downtime for API means 3.3% downtime per day - it's crazy high.

I want to just disable `reneg-sec` altogether, at most set it to renegotiate once a day. What are the implications of this?

My understanding is that `reneg-sec` is used to protect from SWEET32 attach, but [this page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/SWEET32) suggests that since my cipher is `AES-256-GCM` my connection is not susceptible to it? When why do I even need to renegotiate ever?

Answer (score 0):

reneg-sec 0

put this in Open VPN profile file.